# python how to solve errno 13 permission denied using shutil?

Tags: python, windows, shutil, errno

Hi im new to python and im trying to make a script to sort songs but I keep getting permission errors. The script is able to make the folders but when it comes to copying the file (line 32 shutil.copy(inPath, artistFolder + albumFolder) the error comes up.

I have tried changing windows folder permissions running python and vs code as admin as well as using different shutil copy commands (copy, copy2, copyfile and move). I've also tried using different folders on different drives. Using windows 11 and python version 3.10.6.

```
#Import nessesary libraries
import shutil, os
from tinytag import TinyTag

# Define music file
music_filetype = ('mp3', 'm4a', 'flac', 'wav')

def main():
    print('start')

    #Specify input and output directory
    inPath = 'D:\\Music\Test'
    outPath = 'D:\\Music'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inPath):
        for file in files:
            if (file.endswith(music_filetype)):
                print(root+"/"+str(file))
                   
                #try:

                temp_track = TinyTag.get(root + '\\' + file) # temp_track is variable used to access audio tags
                artistFolder = outPath + '/' + temp_track.albumartist # Create folder named for artist
                albumFolder = temp_track.album # Create folder for album


                if os.path.exists(artistFolder): #check if artist folder exists
                    print('folder found')
                    if os.path.exists(artistFolder + albumFolder): #check if album folder exists
                        shutil.copy(inPath, artistFolder + albumFolder) #copy song to folder if folders exist

                elif not os.path.exists(artistFolder + albumFolder): #check if folders don't exist
                    os.makedirs(artistFolder) #create folders
                    os.makedirs(artistFolder + albumFolder)
                    shutil.copy(inPath, artistFolder + albumFolder) #copy song

                #except Exception:
                    #print(root+"/"+str(file), " Error")

main()
```

```
Exception has occurred: PermissionError
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Music\\Test'
  File "D:\Users\User\Documents\Python_projects\Music_sorter\Music_sorter.py", line 32, in main
    shutil.copy(inPath, artistFolder + albumFolder) #copy song to folder if folders exist
```

Comment: `inPath` is a directory, `shutil.copy()` doesn't allow a directory for the `src` argument. I don't know why this presents as a `PermissionError` rather than a `IsADirectoryError`, maybe a Windows thing.

Comment: Your use of the double slash is inconsistent `'D:\\Music\Test'` and you should use **os.path.join**